# Looking for a scifi book about simulating colonizing another world

Tags: story-identification, novel

The book I am looking for was set in the future, overpopulation and poverty were everywhere. A group of homeless/poor kids (maybe young adults) went to a special building where they were placed into simulators several times (i.e., they went back home between each session) where they explored another planet.

At the end of the book, they went there again but soon find out that this time it was the real planet, not just a simulation, and they start rebuilding society.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Invitation to the Game by Monica Hughes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invitation_to_the_Game